Horror movie where female protagonist gets kidnapped and held captive in an old white house; male friend tries to rescue her
I originally watched this horror movie on demand around 2013. 

The female protagonist had been kidnapped, and her male friend (ex-boyfriend?) followed her to this old white house to rescue her at night. The house is dark - no lights
He finds her and attempt to leave said house when the occupants (a couple of creepy guys and old lady) stop them, killing the guy and taking the woman back.
The woman is found upstairs with her "sisters", where she is able to fulfill some prophecy.
Apparently her family is part of a cult - I think the old woman was the grandmother. 

EDIT
V/H/S was a very good guess; yet sadly, is not the movie. The very ending of the movie shows the captive woman no longer herself, but in a sedated and submissive state surrounded by some of her captors.
I'm starting to remember vague parts of the film. Like earlier in the film, she was hospitalized after some traumatic event and then released to be on her own. Her friends were suspicious of her physical or mental health, but she wanted to just move forward.

@mrmre It seems you have created two different accounts. You might want to merge your two accounts by following the instructions provided here. This will enable you to take full control of your posts, including being able to comment, edit and accept any possible answers.

This sounds to me like Paranormal Activity 3

he next day, Kristi asks her mother to take them to her grandmother Lois's house in Moorpark, California, but she refuses. After Julie encounters frightening activity herself, she agrees to go to Lois's home. Dennis sets up another camera in their new bedroom. At 1am, they are awoken and hear disturbances. Julie goes to investigate; when she fails to return, Dennis goes to look for her.
They find Katie crying by the stairs near Julie's body. Dennis approaches Katie from behind, but when he places his hand on her shoulder, Katie turns around and unleashes a demonic scream that throws him to the other side of the room, injuring his leg. Katie flees and Dennis tries to crawl toward Julie's body. Lois stands in his way, and Dennis's body is violently contorted, killing him. Lois then beckons to Kristi and Katie and says "Let's get ready". As they head upstairs together

Here's the particular scene:




This could be one episode of V/H/S

They head out to a Halloween party at a friend's house, only to end up at the wrong place. Sneaking inside, they begin to experience paranormal phenomena and decide they are at a haunted house and have fun with it. In the attic they find several men gathered around a young woman whom they've suspended from the rafters, apparently performing an exorcism. The men are chanting "cast you down", and the boys exuberantly join in, "cast him down". One of the men reacts angrily to their presence and physically assaults the young woman. More violent, overtly threatening paranormal phenomena then begin to occur and the boys initially flee before realizing they should try to rescue the girl. Returning to the attic, the boys work to untie her and get her to safety, as the house itself comes to life with poltergeist phenomena and ghostly hands coming out of the walls and floors to claim the lives of the woman's captors

Part of the scene can be seen here: 


